# How to combine the color channels and alpha channel from two CIImage?

Tags: objective-c, cifilter, ciimage

I have a `CIImage` from YUV data without alpha plane, and a gray scaled `CIImage`. I want to use the second image as the alpha plane. Currently, gpt tells me to use `CISourceOverCompositing` filter, but it seems that this filter will blend the color of the second image's color. If I convert the gray scaled image into a black mask (0, 0, 0, alpha), then this filter will use black as "background color". However, I just want to **replace** the color instead of **blend** it with another color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can blend your color image with a transparent image, using the grayscale image as a mask:

```
CIImage* clearBackground = [[CIImage clearImage] imageByCroppingToRect:colorImage.extent];

CIFilter* blendFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIBlendWithMask"];
[blendFilter setValue:colorImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
[blendFilter setValue:clearBackground forKey:kCIInputBackgroundImageKey];
[blendFilter setValue:grayscaleImage forKey:kCIInputMaskImageKey];

CIImage* output = [blendFilter outputImage];
```